# converting a string to a class

Tags: java, android, string, class

I'm trying to move between one Activity to another based upon some user input.

I'm trying to use:

```
String myClass = "some_user_input.class"
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myClass);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

...to move from one activity to another.

I can do this ok where I reference my new activity directly in the hard code and don't try to compile it from text, (i.e. classA.class), however I want to be able to build my Intent by passing it some string compiled by the user.

For example if the user inputs B in an edittext, I want to go to `classB.class`
If the user inputs Z, I want to go to `classZ.class`.

Is there any way I can compile the class I want to go to using strings which I then convert to a class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [Classloader.loadClass](http://d.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

Comment: do you have multiple packages

Answer (score 5):

The reflection mechanism allows you to do it:

```
String myClass = "some_user_input";
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(myClass);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), clazz);
```

Note that those classes should be included in the android manifest XML.

Also note that I didn't handle the exception in this example :)

Comment: I tried your code. Its throwing classnotfoundexception. Any idea why?

Comment: It throws an exception because you need to add the full package to the String like `us.foobar.package.some_user_input`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using  `Class.forName()` method:

```
String myClass = "foo.class";
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName(myClass));
startActivity(i);
```